# How can I fix divergente branches problem?

Tags: git, github, merge, branch

I'm new to git and need some help.
I made changes to my branch and then moved to the 'dev' branch making the same changes. When I push to dev I get an error:

```
 ! [rejected]        dev -> dev (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:........'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

So I tried to do a pull, but I get this:

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 1, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (1/1), 768 bytes | 768.00 KiB/s, done.
From github.com:.........
   d287199..78398d3  develop    -> origin/dev
hint: You have divergent branches and need to specify how to reconcile them.
hint: You can do so by running one of the following commands sometime before
hint: your next pull:
hint: 
hint:   git config pull.rebase false  # merge
hint:   git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
hint:   git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only
hint: 
hint: You can replace "git config" with "git config --global" to set a default
hint: preference for all repositories. You can also pass --rebase, --no-rebase,
hint: or --ff-only on the command line to override the configured default per
hint: invocation.
fatal: Need to specify how to reconcile divergent branches.
```

So I went to the other branch and merged to dev.

But on dev I still get this error when I try to do a pull:

```
hint: You can do so by running one of the following commands sometime before
hint: your next pull:
hint: 
hint:   git config pull.rebase false  # merge
hint:   git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
hint:   git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only
hint: 
hint: You can replace "git config" with "git config --global" to set a default
hint: preference for all repositories. You can also pass --rebase, --no-rebase,
hint: or --ff-only on the command line to override the configured default per
hint: invocation.
fatal: Need to specify how to reconcile divergent branches.
```

I try with git pull --ff-only, but doesn't work.
Anybody could help me to understand ?

Comment: "hint: You can replace "git config" with "git config --global" to set a default
 preference for all repositories. You can also pass --rebase, --no-rebase,
 or --ff-only on the command line to override the configured default per
 invocation." (just copy-pasting the hint from the error message. Did you do that?)

Comment: Running `gitk --all` is a nice visual tool to show you what branches and commits you have. Given that `dev` and `origin/dev` have diverged (which gitk will clearly show) you probably want: step 0: make sure all changes are checked in! Step 1: `git branch dev.backup dev`. Step 2: `git rebase origin/dev dev`. Step3: verify that dev looks ok and delete the backup branch. In case of conflicts in step 2 you can use [git-resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3](https://github.com/hlovdal/git-resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3). In case you want to revert everything: `git checkout dev; git reset --hard dev.backup`.